# A formal analytical way to solve system of algebraic equations within integer domain

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, integers

Let's take this famous puzzle as an example.

[image]

I can write it as a system of equations like this
$$
3(100C+10A+R)=(100R+10R+R)
$$
$$
C \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
$$
A \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
$$
R \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
$$
0 \leqslant C \leqslant  9
$$
$$
0 \leqslant A \leqslant  9
$$
$$
0 \leqslant R \leqslant  9
$$

Now how to solve it formally? I can only think about trying all possible combinations of integers from 0 to 9, but it will be too many combinations.

Of course, I can involve some logic like this: for $R+R+R=R$, $R$ can be only 0 or 5. It cannot be 0, because first digit of the result cannot be 0. S0, it can be only 5, etc. This is not a formal method in my opinion.

I am asking if there is a generic way. This system is just an example.

Comment: You can formalize some of it using modular arithmetic
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20modular%20arithmetic%20is,Disquisitiones%20Arithmeticae%2C%20published%20in%201801.

Comment: Usually you also require the letter values to be distinct.  Look up "alphametic".

Answer (score 1):

You have $3R \equiv R \pmod{10}$. Therefore, $2R \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$. Therefore, the values of $R \in [0,9]$ that satisfies this congruence are $0, 5$. As you say, if $R$ takes $0$ then the entire result would be $0$ due to the sum being $RRR \pmod{1000}$. Therefore, $R \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$.

For the next digit, we have to take the carry into account. Since $R \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$, the carry is $1$ (due to $5 + 5 + 5 = 1\times 10 + 5$). Let the carrry be $k$

We have $3A + k \equiv R \pmod{10} \implies 3A + 1 \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$.

Therefore, $3A \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$. Since $\gcd(3,10) = 1$ it has a multiplicative inverse modulo $10$. $3^{-1} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$.

Therefore, $A \equiv 3^{-1} \cdot 4 \equiv 7 \cdot 4 \equiv 28 \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$.

$3A = 3\cdot 8 = 24$. Therefore, the carry is $2$.

For the first digit, we have $3C + 2 \equiv R \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$.

Therefore, $3C \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$. As before, $C \equiv 3^{-1} \cdot 3 \pmod{10}$. i.e., $C \equiv 7 \cdot 3 \equiv 21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.

$C = 1, A = 8, R = 5$.

**CHECK:** $185_{10} + 185_{10} + 185_{10} = 555_{10}$.

You can use the same modular arithmetic in any base for similar problems of other digit lengths also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I read wikipedia article a few times, understand definition but still did not get why $3R \equiv R (mod\ 10)$?

Comment: @Zlelik: The last colum has 3 $R$s. They total to some number whose last digit is $R$. It is right there in the problem statement itself in the visual you have put.